# Search Crawling Frequency

Tags: search, best-practices

For Search, How often should you perform an incremental crawl? I was thinking of doing it every two hours? Is that too often? Are there any best practices in terms of frequency of searching?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how frequently you want search to include recently added content.If the content on any site is updated too frequently (like Sharepoint.StackExchange :-) ) and you want user to search it out, Set high frequency.

However, Remember that Crawling happens at the cost of performance.

Please check this article as well how to plan crawl :  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262794(office.12).aspx

Comment: For reference, even though the TechNet article references MOSS 2007, the information and guidance still applies more or less to SharePoint 2010.

Comment: @SP.net I don't think it is accurate to say "However, Remember that Crawling happens at the cost of performance."  You need to consider crawl impact on users, but you also need to consider crawling when designing a farm.  In a properly designed farm, crawling should have little or no impact though it may require additional WFE servers.

Comment: Agree with @Mike,it will not have any impact on end users. However, more server resources(where crawl happens) and network bandwidth may get used.